# Swift / XCode with Kingfisher- Unable to Load Images from Web

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, amazon-web-services, uipageviewcontroller

I have taken a tutorial on UIPageViewControllers and I am trying to load images that I have saved in Amazon Web Services.

I am trying to swipe through different items on my UIPageController, pulling various images from AWS, I am receiving:

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.:

Model:

```
import UIKit

class PageContentViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

var pageIndex: Int = 0
var strTitle: String!
var strPhotoName: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageView.image = UIImage(named: strPhotoName)
    lblTitle.text = strTitle
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher

class ViewController: UIPageViewController,   UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
var arrPageTitle: NSArray = NSArray()
var arrPagePhoto: NSArray = NSArray()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    arrPageTitle = ["This is The App Guruz", "This is Table Tennis 3D", "This is Hide Secrets"];
    arrPagePhoto = ["https://s3.amazonaws.com/fan-polls/heyward_again.jpg", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/fan-polls/Schwarber.jpg", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/fan-polls/mike_ditka.jpg"];

    self.dataSource = self

    self.setViewControllers([getViewControllerAtIndex(0)] as [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
{
    let pageContent: PageContentViewController = viewController as! PageContentViewController

    var index = pageContent.pageIndex

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound))
    {
        return nil
    }

    index += 1;
    return getViewControllerAtIndex(index)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
{
    let pageContent: PageContentViewController = viewController as! PageContentViewController

    var index = pageContent.pageIndex

    if (index == NSNotFound)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    index += 1;
    if (index == arrPageTitle.count)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    return getViewControllerAtIndex(index)
}

func getViewControllerAtIndex(index: NSInteger) -> PageContentViewController
{
    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageContentViewController") as! PageContentViewController

    pageContentViewController.strTitle = "\(arrPageTitle[index])"
    pageContentViewController.strPhotoName = "\(arrPagePhoto[index])"
    pageContentViewController.imageView.kf_setImageWithURL(arrPagePhoto[index] as! NSURL)

    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index

    return pageContentViewController
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Why you cast from String to NSURL? First make this URL and then use it not just cast it

Comment: I am new to Swift and iOS, can you paste the code?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous comment you cast from String to NSURL.
'String' and 'NSURL' are different object types.
So you need to make a conversion. This will convert your String to NSURL.

```
let imageUrl = NSURL(string: arrPagePhoto[index])
```

Now use this value with Kingfisher

```
pageContentViewController.imageView.kf_setImageWithURL(imageUrl)
```